# How to find the cheapeast combination of products to buy from multiple bundles for a shopping list

Tags: algorithm, math, language-agnostic

Let's say I have different bundles of products, each associated with a price.

```
Name               Price      Products
Fruit Overdose     5$         2 Apples, 1 Orange, 1 Banana
Doctors Darling    1$         1 Apple
The Exotic         3.50$      2 Oranges, 1 Banana
Vitamin C          1.5$       1 Orange
```

And I have a shopping list, e.g. I want to buy:

```
4 Apples, 1 Orange, 2 Bananas.
```

### The question

How would I go about finding the **cheapest combination of bundles** to buy for the given shopping list? **Buying more than requested** by the shopping list **is valid**.

I just need a language agnostic hint how I could approch this problem most efficiently. 
My real world problem is a little bit more complex also including a list of products I already own; but this shouldn't really matter too much.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [dual linear programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_linear_program) problem:

- The objective you want to minimise is the total price, which is a linear function.
- The constraints can be formulated as a matrix equation, where each row corresponds with a bundle, and each column corresponds with a kind of product.

You can solve it by [constructing the dual](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_linear_program#Constructing_the_dual_LP) which will be a standard [linear programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming) problem, applying a standard algorithm such as the [simplex algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex_algorithm), then converting the solution back into a solution to the original dual problem.

Answer (score 2):

This kind of problem can be solved handily with a [SAT/SMT solver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satisfiability_modulo_theories). [Z3](https://theory.stanford.edu/~nikolaj/programmingz3.html) is an open source solver with bindings for many languages, including a nicely integrated binding with [Python](https://ericpony.github.io/z3py-tutorial/guide-examples.htm).

In the solver, you just declare a few variables (4 for the weights of each bundle, and 1 for the total price). Then you write down the different constraints. In this case, the constraints are:

- The weights should be positive.
- The total is calculated by summing the price times the weight of each bundle.
- For each of the fruits, the desired minimum number should be bought.

Note that I calculated the price in cents to be able to work with integers, although that is not strictly necessary for Z3.

The Python code then looks like:

```py
from z3 import *

bundles = [["Fruit Overdose", 5, {'apple': 2, 'orange': 1, 'banana': 1}],
           ["Doctors Darling", 1, {'apple': 1}],
           ["The Exotic", 3.50, {'orange': 2, 'banana': 1}],
           ["Vitamin C", 1.5, {'orange': 1}]]
desired = {'apple': 4, 'orange': 1, 'banana': 2}
num_bundles = len(bundles)

W = [Int(f'W_{i}') for i in range(len(bundles))]  # weight of each bundle: how many to buy of each bundle
TotalPrice = Int('Total')

s = Optimize()
s.add(TotalPrice == Sum([W[i] * int(b[1] * 100) for i, b in enumerate(bundles)]))
s.add([W[i] >= 0 for i in range(len(W))])  # weights can not be negative
for f in desired:
    s.add(Sum([W[i] * b[2][f]  for i, b in enumerate(bundles) if f in b[2]]) >= desired[f])

h1 = s.minimize(TotalPrice)
result = s.check()
print("optimizer result:", result)
if result == sat:
    s.lower(h1)
    m = s.model()
    print(f"The lowest price is: {m[TotalPrice].as_long()/100:.2f}")
    for i,b in enumerate(bundles):
        print(f"  Buying {m[W[i]].as_long()} of {b[0]}")
```

Output:

```
The lowest price is: 10.00
  Buying 2 of Fruit Overdose
  Buying 0 of Doctors Darling
  Buying 0 of The Exotic
  Buying 0 of Vitamin C
```

If you simply change the price of the Fruit Overdose to 6, the result would be:

```
  Buying 0 of Fruit Overdose
  Buying 4 of Doctors Darling
  Buying 2 of The Exotic
  Buying 0 of Vitamin C
```

The algorithm guarantees to find the best solution. In case there are multiple equally good solutions, just one of them is returned.